# grails 3 database migrations

Tags: grails, migration, database-migration

I updated my application to grails 3.1.9 and I have trouble with database migration plugin.

My production application.yml looks like this:

```
   production:
        dataSource:
                driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                dbCreate: none
                url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/something
                username: postgres
                password: postgres
                properties:
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
 dependencies {
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1'
        compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'
    }
```

This is the beginning of the changelog:

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "michal (generated)", id: "1472650791344-1") {
        createTable(tableName: "appointment") {
            column(autoIncrement: "true", name: "id", type: "BIGINT") {
                constraints(primaryKey: "true", primaryKeyName: "appointmentPK")
            }

            column(name: "version", type: "BIGINT")

            column(name: "customer_id", type: "BIGINT")

            column(name: "duration", type: "BLOB(255)")

            column(name: "note", type: "CLOB")

            column(defaultValueComputed: "0", name: "personal_available", type: "BOOLEAN")

            column(defaultValueComputed: "0", name: "personal_booked", type: "BOOLEAN")

            column(name: "provider_id", type: "BIGINT")

            column(name: "start_time", type: "BLOB(255)")

            column(name: "url", type: "VARCHAR(255)")
        }
    }
```

When I run my app in production mode I get this error.

```
SEVERE 8/31/16 3:41 PM: liquibase: changelog.groovy: changelog.groovy::1472650791344-1::michal (generated): Change Set changelog.groovy::1472650791344-1::michal (generated) failed.  Error: ERROR: relation "appointment" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.appointment (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, version BIGINT, customer_id BIGINT, duration BYTEA, note TEXT, personal_available BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0, personal_booked BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0, provider_id BIGINT, start_time BYTEA, url VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT "appointmentPK" PRIMARY KEY (id))]
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "appointment" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.appointment (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, version BIGINT, customer_id BIGINT, duration BYTEA, note TEXT, personal_available BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0, personal_booked BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0, provider_id BIGINT, start_time BYTEA, url VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT "appointmentPK" PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
```

...

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "appointment" already exists
```

I will appreciate any idea, why it does not work.

---

Thank you Gregor Petkin. Setting dbcreate to validate really helped me to fix this error.

Comment: Does it help if you explicitly set your `dbCreate` to `validate` instead of `none`?

Comment: @Gregor Petrin Hi it seemed to help. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `dbCreate` clause and a very inconvenient change of behaviour that caused invalid `dbCreate` values to be ignored. Use `dbCreate: validate` if you don't want Hibernate to mess with your database and interfere with the database migration.

Plugins can contribute values to a Grails application so they can provide sensible defaults and it works from the ground up: first come the plugins one by one, then at last the `application.yml` has a chance to override anything they've set. For ease of developing and testing, plugins are also standalone Grails applications so many of them will have a `dbCreate` set.

The inconvenient change that happened was that now an invalid `dbCreate` option will get ignored before overriding the value left there by the *most recent, randomly selected plugin* to have had a chance of contributing to the configuration (that plugin might as well use `create-drop` which could be very inconvenient even in a development environment - in fact, newer Grails versions will ignore the `dbCreate` setting from plugins because the current behaviour is so dangerous).

So now when the database migration runs, an `update` or `create-drop` setting was already used by Hibernate to create your tables and therefore the database migration fails. Configuring the value to `validate` should provide a valid replacement for overriding whatever the plugins have set.

Answer (score 1):

Seems odd that the table already exists, but I encountered something like this in `dev` environment last night so I know it can happen. For example, even though you have `dbCreate: none` maybe the `hbm2ddl` migration tool was executed due to a bug. Check the logs.

Or maybe your `databasechangelog` table was accidentally cleared for some reason. Check to see if there's a corresponding row for that particular changeset in your databasechangelog table.

One thing you can do for this particular changeset is add a `tableExists` pre-condition to the changeset and use `onFail="MARK_RAN"` to mark the changeset as `EXECUTED` if the table already exists. The author of Liquibase once wrote that pre-conditions should be used sparingly due to performance issues. So if you find yourself creating a pre-condition for each changeset you might want to reconsider.

On that note, if you receive this error for more changesets you might need to use `dbm-changelog-sync` (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/1.4.0/ref/Maintenance%20Scripts/dbm-changelog-sync.html) to mark all changesets as "executed", essentially telling Liquibase to ignore them during those changesets on subsequent reboots of the server.

If there are some changesets that you actually want to be executed (and not ignored) -- for example, you made a few changes recently -- then you can tag the "to-be-ignored" changesets using a context and then run the `dbm-changelog-sync` command with those values as the `context` argument.

See the following links for more info.
* http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/1.4.0/ref/Maintenance%20Scripts/dbm-changelog-sync.html
* http://www.liquibase.org/2014/11/contexts-vs-labels.html